# Making Quartz jobs unit-testable

Tags: java, scala, quartz

I have some old code that is supposed to allow us to first schedule Quartz tasks (that get database persisted) and later on get executed by Quartz. The problem is that the job code looks something like:

```
class MyJob extends Job {
  def execute(context: JobExecutionContext) {
    ServiceA.m() <-- Singleton call
    ...
    ServiceB.n() <-- Singleton call
  }
}
```

I was trying to refactor our code to be more inversion-of-control friendly, so I would like to make `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` non-singletons. But I'm failing to see how.. a Quartz `Job` needs to have a 0-args constructor, so I can't pass my dependencies that way (which would have been ideal).

Any workaround that I don't know of? I would like to avoid IoC frameworks, I'm quite content with passing my parameters as implicits in Scala.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case if you can't pass service dependencies via constructor, probably extracting base implementation without dependencies might help - but this looks a bit boiler-plate:

```
  // Base implementation without direct service instantiation 
  trait BaseMyJob extends Job {
    protected val serviceA: ServiceA
    protected val serviceB: ServiceB

    def execute(context: JobExecutionContext) {
      serviceA.m()
      ...
      serviceB.n()
    }
  }

  // Used in your production code via Quartz 
  class ProductionMyJob extends BaseMyJob {
    override protected val serviceA: ServiceA = ServiceA()
    override protected val serviceB: ServiceB = ServiceB()
  }

  // Somewhere in your test spec
  val mockServiceA = mock[ServiceA]
  val mockServiceB = mock[ServiceB]

  val testJob: BaseMyJob = class TestMyJob extends BaseMyJob {
    override protected val serviceA: ServiceA = ServiceA()
    override protected val serviceB: ServiceB = ServiceB()
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Quartz will instantiate Jobs (the 0-args constructor, that is) for you by reflection. I don't see how this can answer my question.

Comment: @devouredelysium Excuse me, I don't not a know Quartz in details, but as you mentioned because it requires 0 argument construction, which leads to the problem in injecting mocks, I thought that extracting base class with methods via which you can inject them might help.

Comment: It doesn't because Job instances are never created by you, they're always created by Quartz: you call `JobBuilder.newJob(classOf[myJob])` to get an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can pass them via constructor. Just have two constructors:

```
    class MyJob(serviceA: Foo, serviceB: Bar) extends Job {
       def this() = this(ServiceA, ServiceB)
       def execute(context: JobExecutionContext) = {
          serviceA.foo()
          serviceB.bar()
       }
     }

     val testMe = new MyJob(mock[Foo], mock[Bar])
```

Comment: ... Quartz instantiates Job instances for you, so this doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @devouredelysium Huh? What exactly "does not make sense" to you? Let quartz instantiate what it wants. I don't see a problem.

Comment: Your plan to avoid having my class depend on a singleton in its `execute()` method is to still depend on a singleton at the constructor level? What are we gaining with this, really?

Comment: @devouredelysium . For your test, you use the other constructor, and pass the mocks (or whatever you want) in to be used instead of the singleton(s), like shown on the last line. Quartz still uses default constructor, which initializes with the singleton.

Comment: I see. It's a workaround, but will only work for unit-testing (I recognize I wrote "unit-testable" in the OP). I was hoping someone with Quartz knowledge would know of an alternative API to avoid having this problem in the first place.

Comment: @devouredelysium what exactly is "the problem in the first place"? If it is not about unit testing, then what? What is the goal here?

Comment: 1) Allow the testing of the system (unit, integration); 2) Ideally have a clear design.

Comment: @devouredelysium so, I explained to you earlier how to allow for testing, that leaves the second point then, right? What specifically about this design do you find "unclear"?